# Insert Calendar by URL, Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) documentation, you can insert a calendar into a users calendar list by a calendar id. However, what if the calendar is coming from a different endpoint? The endpoint we have downloads a `.ics` file.

This can be achieved manually by going to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings/addbyurl and pasting in the specified url. How can I achieve this using the API?

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* the calendar you're inserting is a google calendar?

I think you might have to create/insert the calendar, and then import the events into it using your .ics file.

Inserting new calendar API: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert

And then [import](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/import) if you have an iCalUID in the event info or [insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) otherwise. It's a lot less clean than just using the .ics file though. I suppose you could try to figure out what that part of the UI uses but I doubt it'll accept ad-hoc requests.

Comment: No, sorry I need to clarify that this is **not** a Google calendar. It is a third party url that contains a download for an `.ics` file

Comment: Yeah, I believe `insert`ing into a calendar only works with other google calendars unfortunately. I agree though that it would be great to be able to add an .ics file via the API!